# VS Code Vue <template> <script> <style> autosuggestion

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

It's been a time since I have been programming with Vue.
But when I started entering something like `vuedef` in a newly created `.vue` file it auto-suggested me the following instead of writing it all on my own:

```html
<template>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I can't remember how I did that but I guess it was a certain word I had to type.
Maybe it comes from an VS-Code Addon?

Comment: maybe you need [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vuedef` comes with Vetur: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur

For any modern Vue3 apps, you can use Volar (it's officially the one to use now too): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar

Those 2 are also quite nice:

- Vue3 snippets: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hollowtree.vue-snippets
- Vue snippets: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sdras.vue-vscode-snippets

You should have plenty of choice after that!

---

You can also create your own snippets of course directly into VScode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets